# Redraw shiny plot after updating data frame?

Tags: r, shiny

I have built a Shiny app with a database backend -

Im trying to reload the dataframe `current_data_frame` and redraw the plot using it when `input$draw_plot` (action button) is pressed.

I am having trouble re-drawing the plot after recalling the data frame?

Any ideas what I am missing??

snippet from server.R

```
  current_data_frame = data.frame(matrix(ncol = 4, nrow = 0))
  names( current_data_frame ) <- c("sample_id", "call", "intensity_A" , "intensity_B")


  # OBSERVE BUTTON PRESS & UPDATE DATA FRAME
  observeEvent( input$draw_plot, {
                current_data_frame <- get_data_frame( input$probeset_id , input$study_id , input$batch_id)

                }) 

  vals <- reactiveValues(
                        keeprows = rep(TRUE, nrow( current_data_frame ))
                        )

  output$call_plot <- renderPlot({
                        # Lists for holding unactive_points                      
                        keep    <- current_data_frame[ vals$keeprows, , drop = FALSE]
                        exclude <- current_data_frame[ !vals$keeprows, , drop = FALSE]
                        # Le plot 
                        ggplot(keep, aes( intensity_A , intensity_B)) +
                          geom_point(aes(colour = factor(call), shape = factor(call)) )  #+ 
                          #geom_point(data = exclude, shape = 21 , fill = NA, colour = "black", alpha = 0.25)

                        })

                        # Toggle click points 
                        observeEvent( input$call_plot_click, {
                          res <- nearPoints(current_data_frame, input$call_plot_click, allRows = TRUE)

                        vals$keeprows <- xor(vals$keeprows, res$selected_)
                        })

                        # Toggle points that are brushed when clicked 

                        observeEvent(input$exclude_toggle, {
                          res <- brushedPoints(current_data_frame, input$call_plot_brush, allRows = TRUE)

                          vals$keeprows <- xor(vals$keeprows, res$selected_)
                        })

                        # Reset all points 

                        observeEvent( input$exclude_reset, {
                          vals$keeprows <- rep( TRUE, nrow(current_data_frame))
                        })

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to make `current_data_frame` a reactive value. You can either do that by returning it inside of a `reactive` or by adding it to your `vals` object, including using `vals$current_data_frame` everywhere you currently use `current_data_frame` and changing `vals` to look something like this:

```
vals <- reactiveValues(keeprows = rep(TRUE, nrow( current_data_frame )),
                       current_data_frame = current_data_frame
                        )
```

which will set `vals$current_data_frame` to the default you defined at the start of your code the first time, then allow you to change it every time the `observeEvent` is triggered.

Comment: Tried the second option, still nothing happens on action, I did have to remove the leading comma from your snippet tho

Comment: Can you construct a reproducible example? It is hard to say what is happening with out that. (Thanks for the comma catch -- I'll fix it now)

Answer (score 1):

Managed to answer this myself -

Wrapped the whole output$call_plot in the response function. Now it redraws + fetches new data each time the button is pressed.

Code below...

```
observeEvent( input$draw_plot, {
                current_data_frame <- get_data_frame( input$probeset_id , input$study_id , input$batch_id)



  vals <- reactiveValues(
                        keeprows = rep(TRUE, nrow( current_data_frame ))
                        )

  output$call_plot <- renderPlot({
                        # Lists for holding unactive_points                      
                        keep    <- current_data_frame[ vals$keeprows, , drop = FALSE]
                        exclude <- current_data_frame[ !vals$keeprows, , drop = FALSE]
                        # Le plot 
                        ggplot(keep, aes( intensity_A , intensity_B)) +
                          geom_point(aes(colour = factor(call), shape = factor(call)) )  #+ 
                          #geom_point(data = exclude, shape = 21 , fill = NA, colour = "black", alpha = 0.25)

                        })

                        # Toggle click points 
                        observeEvent( input$call_plot_click, {
                          res <- nearPoints(current_data_frame, input$call_plot_click, allRows = TRUE)

                        vals$keeprows <- xor(vals$keeprows, res$selected_)
                        })

                        # Toggle points that are brushed when clicked 

                        observeEvent(input$exclude_toggle, {
                          res <- brushedPoints(current_data_frame, input$call_plot_brush, allRows = TRUE)

                          vals$keeprows <- xor(vals$keeprows, res$selected_)
                        })

                        # Reset all points 

                        observeEvent( input$exclude_reset, {
                          vals$keeprows <- rep( TRUE, nrow(current_data_frame))
                        })

                    })  

})
```