# R Shiny application for comparing two chronologies

Tags: r, shiny

I am providing here an executable simple R shiny application to plot two lines based on column names.

```
library(shiny)
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      uiOutput("moreControls")
      ),

    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                  tabPanel("Cross dating", plotOutput("plot1"))

      )
    )
  )

))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    datasetInput <- data.frame(chrono_A = rnorm(16,0),chrono_B = rnorm(16,0))
    row.names(datasetInput) <- c(seq(2000, 2015))
    col_names <- colnames(datasetInput)

  output$moreControls <- renderUI({
    checkboxGroupInput("variable", "Filter Options", col_names)
  })

  # Plot data
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({

    datasetInput_short <- mutate(datasetInput, year = as.numeric(row.names(datasetInput)))
    datasetInput_short <- melt(datasetInput_short, id = c("year"))
    datasetInput_short <- dplyr::filter(datasetInput_short, variable %in% input$variable)

    ggplot(datasetInput_short, aes(x = year, y = value, group = variable, col = variable)) + 
        geom_line() + theme_bw() +  ylim(-3, 3)

      })

})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I would like to add two features, which would allow me to move the plotted lines in two ways:

1. By adding a window where I can directly add the final year for the curve (ideally, the current final year would be entered automatically)
2. By adding two additional buttons (+ and -), and by clicking them I move each line by one year

Please, see the image below: 
[image]

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: When I search for “shiny redraw” I get multiple hits including some answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40246849/redraw-shiny-plot-after-updating-data-frame?r=SearchResults

Comment: @42- Thank you for your comment, but my question is more about how to create appropriate custom gadgets that would allow me to slide lines left or right… Any suggestion in this direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reread your description, maybe this might be helpful, though not entirely sure this is what you have in mind.

You can add two `textInput` widgets and then add filters to your data so that the data displayed for A and B have years less than these values.

In addition, you can have `reactiveValues` that include an offsets for A and B that increase/decrease when the buttons are pressed. These offsets will change the year column from the filtered data for A and/or B.

```
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  datasetInput <- data.frame(chrono_A = rnorm(16,0),chrono_B = rnorm(16,0))
  row.names(datasetInput) <- c(seq(2000, 2015))
  col_names <- colnames(datasetInput)

  rv <- reactiveValues(offset_A = 0, offset_B = 0)

  observeEvent(input$but_plus_A, {
    rv$offset_A <- rv$offset_A + 1
  })

  observeEvent(input$but_minus_A, {
    rv$offset_A <- rv$offset_A - 1
  })

  observeEvent(input$but_plus_B, {
    rv$offset_B <- rv$offset_B + 1
  })

  observeEvent(input$but_minus_B, {
    rv$offset_B <- rv$offset_B - 1
  })

  datasetInput_short <- reactive({
    datasetInput %>%
      mutate(year = as.numeric(row.names(.))) %>%
      pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("chrono_"), names_to = "variable", values_to = "value") %>%
      dplyr::filter(variable %in% input$variable,
                    (variable == "chrono_A" & year < input$sel_A) | (variable == "chrono_B" & year < input$sel_B)) %>%
      mutate(year = if_else(variable == "chrono_A", year + rv$offset_A, year),
             year = if_else(variable == "chrono_B", year + rv$offset_B, year))
  })

  output$moreControls <- renderUI({
    list(
      checkboxGroupInput("variable", "Filter Options", col_names),
      textInput("sel_A", "Year A", 2015),
      actionButton("but_plus_A", "", icon = icon("plus")),
      actionButton("but_minus_A", "", icon = icon("minus")),
      textInput("sel_B", "Year B", 2015),
      actionButton("but_plus_B", "", icon = icon("plus")),
      actionButton("but_minus_B", "", icon = icon("minus"))
    )
  })

  # Plot data
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(datasetInput_short(), aes(x = year, y = value, group = variable, col = variable)) + 
      geom_line() + theme_bw() +  ylim(-3, 3)
  })

})
```

**Edit**:

Based on OP comment below, say you do not know the column names, but there are always 2 columns to work with, you can do the following. You can use the column names vector `col_names` when filtering.

```
datasetInput_short <- reactive({
  datasetInput %>%
    mutate(year = as.numeric(row.names(.))) %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = all_of(col_names), names_to = "variable", values_to = "value") %>%
    dplyr::filter(variable %in% input$variable,
                 (variable == col_names[1] & year < input$sel_A) | (variable == col_names[2] & year < input$sel_B)) %>%
    mutate(year = if_else(variable == col_names[1], year + rv$offset_A, year),
           year = if_else(variable == col_names[2], year + rv$offset_B, year))
})
```

It is possible to dynamically generate more than 2 sets of inputs (for example, using 3: A, B, and C) but that would be a bit more complex.

Comment: Yes, this is the right direction. Amazing, very helpful! Thank you very much.

Comment: Your solution works well for cases when variables are known in advance – and this was the case in my question. Can you please give me a hint, how to transform your example into more interactive, where column names (e.g. column_A and column_B) are unknown in advance? In reality, the application I am working on, firstly opens csv, where names of chronologies are unknown. The idea is to slide those left/right to get perfect match. I know this is advanced topic, but any direction is highly appreciated.

Comment: @JerryTheForester yes, you can modify `datasetInput_short` expression if the column names are unknown (see edited answer above). Hope this is helpful.

Comment: yes, this works excellent. Thank you for your contribution to my Shiny application! So, to go from here to the next level - unknown number of variables - is quite a big step, right? I have been reading about for loops inside Shiny... Is there any better way than for loops based on the dis_name length?

Comment: @JerryTheForester just to clarify, if you have 3 variables/columns (e.g., A, B, and C determined from a csv file), you're looking to have 3 text boxes and 3x2 = 6 buttons dynamically created? And then filter the data based on those widgets?

Comment: Yes, the number of columns always corresponds to the number of text boxes and the number action buttons (multiplied by 2)...

Comment: @JerryTheForester This would be complex, but here are some suggestions. Would first look at [dynamic observers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38950886/generate-observers-for-dynamic-number-of-inputs), since you will have multiple dynamic buttons and need to have different observers for these items. This will require additional reactive values to track observers. Also, when you filter your data for the plot, you will need to probably "join" a table containing the `input` results from the text fields with your data...

Comment: Thanks for the directions. I see I have some homework to do. 
When I come up with the solution, I’ll post it here so others can benefit from it. Thanks for your contribution.